# Firefox Bootstrapped Add-On Injecting before load

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to add event listeners for a document before a page has been navigated to using a Bootstrapped add-on?  I would like to see what page the user wants to navigate to as well as later after the page loads to inspect the DOM.  I need to run code in the HTML content context.

In the past I used a toolbar XUL and included javascript within it and it would load before the HTML page loaded.

Comment: Do you want to edit the source/html that gets rendered? If this is true than ill have to give different solution. But if you want to acess dom before `DOMContentLoaded` see solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i looked into doing stuff before DOMContentLoaded sometime ago and found out there is a document inserted observer.

order of events after running research code at bottom

1. `readystate` changes to `interactive` (i think multiple times, not sure)
2. `readystate` changes to `complete`
3. `DOMContentLoaded` event fires
4. `load` event fires *(Sometimes load doesnt fire, if you might have to change `addEventListener` with capture arugment (3rd argument) as false or true)*

apparently there should be `readystate` `loading` before all of this but i can never catch it i dont know why.

after running the code in scratchpad, browser environemnt of course, then load a new page and watch the error console it will throw these reports in this order:

```
ready state changed! ("interactive") Scratchpad/4:18
02:28:07.873 ready state changed! ("complete") Scratchpad/4:18
02:28:07.874 DOMContentLoaded event fired! Scratchpad/4:53
02:28:07.938 Load event fired! Scratchpad/4:45
```

here is the research code. it adds a the listeners and observer to see whats firing.

```
var {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;
var os = Cc['@mozilla.org/observer-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
var LMObserver;

function myObserver() {
  this.register();
}

myObserver.prototype = {
    observe: function (subject, topic, data) {
        //Cu.reportError(subject);
        //Cu.reportError(data);
        //i think subject is window element
        subject.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //loading
            //interactive
            //complete
            Cu.reportError('ready state changed! ("' + subject.readyState + '")');
            //var body = subject.documentElement.querySelector('body')
//you want to change title so you would do that here do something like: if (subject.readystate == 'complete') { subject.title = 'blah blah' }
            //Cu.reportError('has body element: ' + body)
        }

    },
    register: function () {
        os.addObserver(this, 'document-element-inserted', false);
    },
    unregister: function () {
        os.removeObserver(this, 'document-element-inserted', false);
    }
};


//below this is the DOMContentLoaded thing i put this here so we can see what fires in what order
var pageLoad = function(event) {
    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
    if (win && win.frameElement) {
      return;
    }
    Cu.reportError('Load event fired!');
}

var pageDOMContentLoaded = function(event) {
    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
    if (win && win.frameElement) {
      return;
    }
    Cu.reportError('DOMContentLoaded event fired!');
}


LMObserver = new myObserver;
gBrowser.addEventListener("load", pageLoad, true);
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageDOMContentLoaded, true);
//gBrowser.removeEventListener("load", pageLoad, true);
//gBrowser.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageDOMContentLoaded, true);
//LMObserver.unregister();
```

Here's some more indepth research on `load` events added with `true` or `false` as capture argument: https://github.com/Noitidart/event-listener-experiment-DOMC-and-load/blob/master/bootstrap.js